# Code not working after converted form tag into form_open in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, form-helpers

I changed my code as form tages to form_open methods. After changing the actions are not working as previous.I have enabled csrf protection too.

previous code;

```
   <form action="<?php echo site_url();?>/admin/user_screen" method ="post" enctype="multipart/form_data" name="form">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">

   ............form contents..................

   </form>
```

new code;

```
<?php 
  $attributes= array('name'=>'form');
  echo form_open('admin/screen_flow',$attributes);
?>

.....form contents.....

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: While you are using form tag at that time your action URL would be "www.yoursite.com/admin/user_screen" like wise, and by changing it to form_open() and if your form is in some deep path e.g. your URL page would be www.yoursite.com/xyz/abc/yourform and you are trying to access action page it would be as "www.yoursite.com/xyz/abc/admin/screen_flow" so in this case you have to give full path to the action. please try like wise. Hope it works good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

use this `form_open_multipart` instead of `form_open`

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/screen_flow', array('name' => 'form'));?>

.....form contents.....

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is just in the first line ...

***Use this :***

```
$attributes= array('name'=>'form');
```

Instead of

```
$attributes= array('name'='form');
```

Hopes it help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
   echo form_open_multipart(site_url().'admin/screen_flow', ['name' => 'form']);
?>

.....form contents.....

<?php echo form_close();?>
```